# how to get datalist value in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

my data list contain id and groupName. id as 1,2,3,4,5 groupName as Friend,family,school,college,sivagiri.

i am displaying the groupname, user select the group name means , i want to get id for the select group.

my code is :

```
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 5%">
            <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"
                style="color: #ffcc33"></i></span> <input class="form-control"
                placeholder="Select Group" id="acqGroup" list="group" />
            <datalist id="group">
            </datalist>

        </div>
```

and jsp code:

```
                        $.each(modelMap.distAcqGroupList, function(index, groupBO) {
                                $("#group").append($("<option></option>").text(groupBO.groupName));

                            });
```

now the data list is loading perfectly , and selected value is displayed but i want to get an id for selected value. i try as

```
                 $("#acqGroup").blur(function() {           
                        var group = $("#acquaintanceGroup").val();
                        alert(group);

                    });
```

it display only select item text, i want the id, please help me.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBMrR/)

Comment: how abt `$("#someId").attr("id");`

Comment: ya ,  navin i want get the index of the array

Comment: which array ? the one you gave in fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

My version in getting class name of selected option from datalist. Kinda messy though

```js
$("#account-list").blur(function() {
  var val = $("#account-list").val(); // get the value from #account-list

  // for loop
  var cn;
  var x = document.getElementById("account-ids").options.length; //get option total = 4
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    var v = document.getElementById("account-ids").options[i].value; //get values by index
    if (val == v) { // compare option value from #account-list value
      cn = document.getElementById("account-ids").options[i].className; // get the cname
      i = x; // get ou of the loop
      // cn now holds the class name of that selected option from datalist
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input list="accounts" id="account-list" />
  <datalist id="accounts">
    <option class="1" value="Juan De Lacruz"></option>
    <option class="2" value="Jan Doe"></option>
    <option class="3" value="Foo Bar"></option>
    <option class="4" value="Nme Name"></option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```